# MYSQL Create Summary View

Tags: mysql, view

Simplified example of my situation:

I have two tables (one for 2017, one for 2018) which have two columns, `Category` and `Cost`.

The two tables may share some `Categories` but they each may also have some unique ones.

I'm trying to create a "master" view which contains a list of all categories between both tables.

E.g. This is what I have

```
Table: 2017_Summary
+------------------+----------+
| Category         | Cost     |
+------------------+----------+
| Home Improvement | -1000.00 |
| Mortgage         |  -800.00 |
| Groceries        |  -500.00 |
| Bills            |  -400.00 |
| Taxes            |  -300.00 |
+------------------+----------+

Table: 2018_Summary
+------------------+----------+
| Category         | Cost     |
+------------------+----------+
| Mortgage         |  -750.00 |
| Groceries        |  -550.00 |
| Bills            |  -400.00 |
| Car Payment      |  -350.00 |
| Taxes            |  -300.00 |
+------------------+----------+
```

This is what I want:

```
View: Summary
+------------------+-----------+-----------+
| Category         | 2017_Cost | 2018_Cost |
+------------------+-----------+-----------+
| Home Improvement |  -1000.00 |      0.00 |
| Mortgage         |   -800.00 |   -750.00 |
| Groceries        |   -500.00 |   -550.00 |
| Bills            |   -400.00 |   -400.00 |
| Car Payment      |      0.00 |   -350.00 |
| Taxes            |   -300.00 |   -300.00 |
+------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

I can figure out how to create this view containing the those `Categories` that are common between the two tables, but I can't figure out how to also include those that are unique to each table and fill in `0.00` in for those values. (I'm also OK with filling in `NULL` instead of `0.00` if it is easier.)

This is how I figured out the view which contains the common `Categories`, but this isn't exactly what I want:

```
CREATE VIEW SUMMARY (CATEGORY,2017_COST,2018_COST) AS
     SELECT A.CATEGORY,A.COST,B.COST FROM 2017_SUMMARY A, 2018_SUMMARY B
     WHERE A.CATEGORY = B.CATEGORY;
```

And final question: Would this view get considerably more complicated if more than two tables were used (e.g. also combining with a `2016_Summary` table)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an inermediate view for the category (the use of subselect in not allowed  in view for some mysql versions) and a pair of left join for the cost

```
  CREATE VIEW all_category  AS
  select category 
  from 2018_Summary
  union 
  select category 
  from 2017_Summary
  ;

  CREATE VIEW SUMMARY AS 
  select a.category, ifnull(b.cost,0) as 2017_cost, ifnull(c.cost, 0)as 2018_cost
  from all_category a
  left join 2017_Summary b on a.category = b.category 
  left join 2018_Summary c on a.category = c.category  
  ;
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, and actually is there a way to place `0` in the placeholders instead of `NULL`? At first I didn't think it would matter, but when you sort ascending, it puts the `NULLS` at top but I would like them at the bottom.